# C#: why 'bool' instead of 'boolean'

Tags: c#, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Bool and Boolean types in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134746/what-is-the-difference-between-bool-and-boolean-types-in-c)

Why does C# use the word `bool` intead of `boolean` for boolean types?

(I just wasted 5 mins trying to work out why my code wasn't compiling!)

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469679/why-boolean-and-bool

Comment: Same as asking why `int` instead of `integer`. Or `struct` instead of `structure` or...

Comment: Or `class` instead of `classture`... Oh, wait.

Answer (score 25):

Presumably because that's the keyword C++ uses for its boolean type, and C# retains much of the syntax to help programmers comfortable with that language migrate more easily. Old habits die hard.

It's also shorter, which saves typing. Programmers are a notoriously lazy bunch, and for good reason.

But remember that `bool` is only an *alias* in C# for the [`System.Boolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.aspx) type. You can certainly use `Boolean` instead if you prefer (but of course, you'll have to capitalize it, since C# is case-sensitive).

Answer (score 10):

Same reason it uses int for integer. programmers are lazy. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is just the decision the language designer made, probably because it is shorter. It is also the keyword many languages use.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the same reason they chose `int` instead `Integer` or `Int32` - a similarity with C++!

Answer (score 1):

Probably because if historical reasons. bool and BOOL types were often used in C and C++ libraries that preceded C#.

Answer (score 1):

Because the inventor of the Boolean logic was named Bool*e* (thanks Cody). So you got Bools and boolean operators to operate on them. Makes sense, not?

Comment: Actually, he was named [Boole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole).

Answer (score 0):

bool is simply an alias of `System.Boolean` - meant to save you 3 characters per declaration :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all C style languages use "bool", it's not something that's peculiar to C# by any means...