# whats different in bool and boolean in c# .net

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Bool and Boolean types in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134746/what-is-the-difference-between-bool-and-boolean-types-in-c)

What is the difference between bool and Boolean in c# .net

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134746/what-is-the-difference-between-bool-and-boolean-types-in-c

Comment: I don't know the exact link but there are other post with the exact same question. So voted for duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) states: 
"The bool keyword is an alias of System.Boolean"
No difference.

Answer (score 0):

The 'bool' keyword is an alias for System.Boolean. There is no functional difference between the two.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. `bool` is an alias for `System.Boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

`bool` is the C# keyword, `Boolean` is the .Net type. There is no difference between them, the C# keyword is just another name for the system type.

There is a similar "duality" with `string` and `String`, string being a C# keyword and String the .Net type.