# Difference between bool/Boolean, string/String etc

Tags: c#, string, types, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)

What is the big difference between these datatypes? and were should I use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String vs string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c) and [What is the difference between Bool and Boolean types in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134746/what-is-the-difference-between-bool-and-boolean-types-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, there is no difference. They are just alias of each other, see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds(VS.80).aspx for a complete list.

Comment: that means that I can use bool or Boolean. Because in java theres a difference.

Comment: @Holyoxx: yes, you can use either one. Consistency among the project is nice, but no one else is going to care.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at: [String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)