# C# string vs String, bool vs Boolean

Tags: c#, string, boolean

are there any diferences between string and String/bool and Boolean? Shoud I prefer using one over other one? Or should I just try to avoid converting between these types (I already noticed that application is able to deal with this convert, but there could be some problem)...or is it just pointless question?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/134746/1037210) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7074/1037210)

Comment: What's the difference between a duck?

Comment: I think, that people, who answer these questions on SO, must receive -1000 votes automatically.

Comment: @Dennis not really. Its acceptable to be not rude to someone new to SO, and an answer is welcome. But I sincerely hope OP removes this question. We already have a lot of this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are the same things - `string` is just an alias for `System.String` and `bool` for `System.Boolean`

Answer (score 5):

They are exactly the same. But I think it's worth noting (in case you have a multi-language persuasion), that in Java, the boolean and Boolean types are **not** the same.

Answer (score 3):

bool is an alias for System.Boolean just as int is an alias for System.Int32. 
See a full list of aliases [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds%28VS.80%29.aspx).
and Example

```
int x = 123;
System.Int32 x = 123;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation, for example for **[bool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**, you'll see that they are just aliases, so any conversions are unnecessary.

I've rarely seen `System.String` and `System.Boolean` used explicitly, the aliases are used much more often (in some projects in 100% of cases, even for calling static methods like `string.Join(...)`)

Answer (score 1):

No differences - just different syntactic sugar as one is a set of keywords and the other a set of types. They compile to the same thing. Most shops/people pick a format they prefer and stick with it... I use the lowercase keywords instead of the type.