# Is Boolean the same as bool in a WCF contract

Tags: c#, wcf, types

If I change an existing DataMember property as part of a WCF contract from Boolean to bool, is this then considered as a change/breach of contract?

Comment: TRY IT OUT BEFORE ASKING.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134746/what-is-the-difference-between-bool-and-boolean-types-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6):

There is *no* difference between `Boolean` and `bool`.  They are one and the same.  Twins.  Compatriots.  Brothers in Arms.  Drinking Buddies.  Compardres.  Smiths & Wessons, Turner and Hooch.  Dumb and Dumber.

Answer (score 1):

bool is an alias for System.Boolean just as string is an alias for System.String

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference! bool is just the alias for System.Boolean!

Answer (score 0):

> If I change an existing DataMember property as part of a WCF contract from Boolean to bool,

bool is an alias to Boolean. There is no difference.

> is this then considered as a change/breach of contract

No, as they are same therefore you won't face any change.